# cancel disable of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help, in my question. I have textarea and button in popup, and with function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);

    $('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
        var textarea_value = $("#id_get_post_description2").val();
        var text_value = $('input[name="textField"]').val();

        if(textarea_value != '' && text_value != '')
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
        else
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
    });
});
```

i'm checking the value elements in textarea and if 0 disable button.

But i have bug, when i call this function in other popup (before there i'm clear textarea and having disable button) my button disable, by default.
How i can fix this?

Screenshot with stage

http://www.ex.ua/800076465918

Comment: Thanks guys all!! for the help!

Comment: I'm resolve my problem just when add $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false); 
in the function calling popup

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest outputting your values to the console.log to verify they are defined nd returning what you expect them to based on your inputs.

Something like:

```
console.log('textarea_value  ' + textarea_value);
```

Then use the browsers debug window tho view the values

Answer (score 0):

Here check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2f89M/4/).

```
var textarea = $('#t');
var button = $('#b');
$(document).ready(function(){
    lCheck();


    textarea.on('keyup', lCheck);
});


function lCheck(){
    if (textarea.val().length == 0) {
        button.attr('disabled', 'true');
    } else {
       button.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

What I do is check the length of the textarea value. If it is 0 I add disabled, if it is more than 0 I remove disabled.

Comment: Putting `lCheck()` inside a `function. () {}` callback is pointless. Just use `textarea.on("keyup", lCheck)`

Comment: @Luxelin, oops, I moved it inside a function last moment to make it run on ready as well. I will fix.

Comment: you should also move the `textarea` event handler inside of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Luxelin yep... The consequences of adding a last moment `ready` and then not thinking.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to give `id` to your button instead of selecting like `$('input[type="submit"]')` otherwise if you have two submit buttons as inputfield, all will be disabled/enabled. AND use `.removeAttr()` of jquery

```
$('#button_id').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: what is your problem 2? @user3731374

Comment: I'm resolve my problem just when add $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false); in the function calling popup, thanks for the help! –  user3731374

Answer (score 0):

jquery recommands to use `.prop()` (since 1.6) to act on this kind of stuff : http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
$('input[type="submit"]').prop( "disabled", false );
```